# Text entered in a multine edittext displays as a single line text in textview

Tags: android-studio

Can same one help me how I can show a text entered in a multiline `EditText` as is? I'm trying to display  the entered text but it behaves as a single line text with no carriage return at each expected end of line.

Can some one help me how to solve this? Below is my XML and how get the text from the EdiText.

```
 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/edittext"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
 android:imeOptions="actionNext">
```

`String message=edittext.gettext().tostring();`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML and your seems to be okay and this too `String message=edittext.getText().toString();`

Remember that the text passed to the `textview` will try to occupy the available width and will go to next line only if there insufficient width to display all the text on single line or if there a carriage return in the passed text.

That means, your text will appear on multiple lines if it has been typed so (with enter or shift+enter) to return to next line. otherwise it will behave as single line text kind of unique sentence.

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMsg"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto"
       android:textColor="@color/msgText" />

Comment: here is my textview.can u please tell me whats wrong .

Comment: @chandu, this should not cause any problem since the EditText inputType is set to textMultiline. But what I suggest is to test using a text with carriage return or line breaks by pressing either enter or shift enter every time you want to start a newline. then if the result still behaves as single line text there might be another issue. Thanks for trial